# How to access braintree functionality from Meteor server

Tags: meteor, braintree

I'm trying to use Braintree in my Meteor application, and I've made a local package of [this Braintree packaging](https://github.com/ripplehq/meteor-braintree), following the instructions of [this blog post on the subject](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages), and the install went fine.

Now though, I have this code:

```js
// defined in server/fixtures.js
Gateway = braintree.connect({
    environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    merchantId: "secret",
    publicKey: "secret",
    privateKey: "secret"
});
```

and it's throwing this error:

```
ReferenceError: braintree is not defined
(etc....)
```

I then tried throwing in this line as recommended by [the Braintree documentation](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/node/guide/getting_paid), but it simply throws an error that "require" isn't defined.

```
var braintree = require("braintree");
```

The Braintree docs uses Express methodologies to make everything happen, but that's not a lot of help here.

The package I referenced earlier defines it's `server.js` with this single line:

```
Braintree = Npm.require("braintree");
```

so I tried changing my references to `Braintree` rather than `braintree`, but this was undefined the exact same way.

How do I get at Braintree to use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server packages require that symbols used outside of the package be exported with `api.export`. It looks like the package you referenced was built prior to meteor [v0.6.5](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v065). As I recall, [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/meteor-feed-archive/linker-package-namespacing) on EventedMind explains how all of this works. I suspect the solution to your problem is just to make your `package.js` look something like:

```js
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.export('Braintree');
  api.use(...);
  api.add_files(...);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this: `package.js:1:24: api is not defined`. I put this line in the local package, that's what you intended correct?

Comment: I also tried to place it in `Package.on_use`, but got: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Environment' of undefined`

Comment: Oh wait hold on, I think I just got it working, `Package.on_use` was correct I just needed to change your line to `api.export('Braintree');` capitalized, since that's what the package uses.

Comment: Yeah that was it, your line needed to be within `Package.on_use`, and it needed to have Braintree capitalized, at least to work with this package. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. :) I updated the answer to be more specific.