# Meteor and paypal integration

Tags: security, paypal, meteor, payment

I'm looking for a "made for meteor" payment system, basically I thought about using Paypal

I browsed the packages on atmospherejs.com and found this [Paypal package one](https://atmospherejs.com/package/paypal)

It seems to work but I feel this is really **not secure**.

- The whole process is sent to the server through a Meteor.call("pay",{my credit card information in clear})
- The client only is getting the transaction callback, it's really not hard to add a server one but still, if the client pays and crash you would like the trusted server to trace the purchase.

Is actually Meteor.call secured ? Is there a more mature way of integrating a payment solution into a Meteor project ?

Comment: Why would `Meteor.call` be insecure? You can view these requests inside your browser console / inspecting your network traffic. It's just sending/receiving data from the server. If you want to have a secure payment process, use a token based system / SSL.

Comment: @BradM the package is sending in clear your visa credentials to the server. If someone is sniffing the network he will get everything. Serving the service through https is a solution but has its cost in term of speed, bandwidth and cpu.

Comment: SSL speed/bandwidth/cpu costs are completely trivial. If you want to have *any* type of security on your site, SSL is an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is not using https then I would not recommend the use of that module.

Just have paypal handle the transaction
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/

And make sure you check the amount paid when paypal postback to your meteor site to confirm the transaction.

Edit:
Make a route for paypal to postback too. Paypal explains it here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

The route you make in meteor should check if the transaction amount and stuff like that is the same as the order you have. This is to make sure people don't mess with the form and pay less then they should.

Comment: How you you catch the callback on the server ?

Comment: OK will look at a Node paypal-ipn-listner package to achieve this, also I might be considering Braintree instead of Paypal which seems to have a working [package on meteor.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154305/how-to-access-braintree-functionality-from-meteor-server)