# Stuck with integrating Braintree with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, braintree

So, I used `sudo npm install -g braintree` to install the package to a clean meteor project and have the following code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){

    Meteor.call('getBraintree')

    braintree.setup("/* very long client token */", 'dropin', {
    container: 'dropin'
    });
};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    var braintreeApi = Meteor.npmRequire('braintree'),
        gateway = braintree.connect({
      environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
      merchantId: "merchantId",
      publicKey: "publicKey",
      privateKey: "privateKey"
    });
  });  

Meteor.methods({
  'getBraintree': function getBraintree(){
    var braintreeWeb = Meteor.npmRequire('braintree-web');
    }
  });
};
```

...and braintree is not defined @ `braintree.connect({` (I have sandbox access and all my keys in order). If I used npm to install the package to my Meteor directory, is there anything further that I'd have to do to my packages.js file [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154305/how-to-access-braintree-functionality-from-meteor-server), considering npm now works with meteor in v1? More generally, how do I configure a project so npm packages can be installed and used?

**Edit: code is updated as of 12/11**

Comment: Are you missing `var braintree = require('braintree')`?

Comment: I experimented with declaring it globally, at the beginning of the startup function, and inside a global startup function...it throws back 'require is not defined'. I'm a beginner with Meteor but this seems like it could have to do with the npm package install?

Comment: @MikePaszkiewicz I've removed the keys that you posted (just in case they were your real keys) please don't post those in a public place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Braintree :) Always feel free to reach out to our support if you are having issues with your integration.

**Update**: I've created an extremely basic Braintree and Meteor [example application](https://github.com/NickTomlin/braintree-meteor-example) that may be of some help you.

Another disclaimer: I know *very* little about Meteor. I'll try to answer the broader non-meteor specific issues, and update with more meteor specific information if I can get it. Here are few potential issues:

1. You need both the client and the server side modules for a Braintree integration, [`braintree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree) is the server-side (node) Braintree library and [`braintree-web`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree-web) is the client side package. I am not sure on the specifics of consuming a client side npm module in Meteor, so it may be easier for you to use a tool like bower or to hot link to the client side javascript by placing a script tag on your page:

   `<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>`
2. `braintree.connect` is a server side method, and as such should only be called on the server (probably once during startup). You'll need it to generate a clientToken to be used on the client side. I have very little experience with Meteor, but I think it is suitable to call `braintree.connect` within `Meteor.startup` on the server:

   ```
           // a better pattern would be to place this in a server/index.js file
           // within your project, which Meteor knows to load as server only code
           Meteor.startup(function () {
             if (Meteor.isServer) {
               var braintree = Meteor.npmRequire('braintree');

               gateway = braintree.connect({
                 environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                 publicKey: process.env.BT_PUBLIC_KEY,
                 privateKey: process.env.BT_PRIVATE_KEY,
                 merchantId: process.env.BT_MERCHANT_ID
               });
             }
           });
   ```
3. `braintree.setup` should only be run on the client side, it is what interacts with the form on the client side.

Comment: Tried running it with the hotlink to `braintree.js` client-side to no avail. Client and server have all the right code sorted as far as I can tell, but braintree is still undefined at `braintree.connect`. Seems like it definitely has to do with meteor and the npm package talking properly.

Comment: @MikePaszkiewicz `braintree` is just a variable, you will need to assign the return of `npmRequire` to it in order to use any of the functionality. E.g. `var braintree = var braintree = Meteor.npmRequire('braintree');`. You could also just use what you are currently assigning it to `braintreeApi` if you wanted to more on common js modules [here](http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/). Also I think `Meteor.methods` should only be used on the server side, so that isn't going to be available to you on the client. I also don't think that `npmRequire` works on the client (at least out of the box).

Comment: You'll also need to do as @Thanish said and use the npmRequire module as it is supposed to be used, e.g. by adding a `packages.json` file with the proper package and version name. There's a how to on using it [here](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-17-using-npm-modules-in-your-application/36)

Comment: @NickTomlin if you like to you can create/maintain a Meteor package for braintree :) . It can do both server and client side stuff.

Comment: @MikePaszkiewicz updated with a link to a Braintree + Meteor example, please let me know if that's of any help!

Comment: @NickTomlin Nick, much appreciated! My problem may have been not declaring the global gateway variable at the beginning of my server code. If I come across anything I'll be sure to make a PR on the repository. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Braintree has two packages on npm. One is for the server-side and the other is for client side.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree will provide the server code (`var gateway = braintree.connect…`)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree-web on the other hand, will provide the code for running in the browser (`braintree.setup("/*very long client token*/", 'dropin', {`).

In the case of meteor, you may need to include both packages. (Make sure to double check that your private key is kept secret on your server! It may be helpful to use the `/server` [special directory](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure) to serve this purpose.)

Comment: Didn't have the braintree-web one installed, but after getting the package, I'm still getting a single error that 'braintree is not defined' when it hits `braintree.connect`. Original code has been edited above per your suggestions and everything seems in its right place.

Answer (score 1):

**require** is not available inside Meteor like that. Use this package https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm to use npm packages.

Comment: Still having trouble after following the readme for the meteor npm package. npm is installed globally, package version is in the .json file, and I've created a Meteor method on the server which is called by the client to require the Braintree package: `var braintreeApi = Meteor.npmRequire('braintree');`. Braintree is still not defined...any input would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you create a `packages.json` file? Check this out https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#defining-packages

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package that is Synchronously Wrapped for meteor and Braintree https://atmospherejs.com/patrickml/braintree